# Dialogflow projects.agent.intents.list

Tags: regex, google-api, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to use Dialogflow's `projects.agent.intents.list` method but I can't manage to understand what I am expected to put for "agent" in the parent string. In [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.intents/list?hl=en) it specifies I am supposed to provide  projects/Project ID/agent. I have provided projects/hr-oadbbl/HR.

To clarify, when using `projects.getAgent` method, with this parent: projects/hr-oadbbl
I get this response object (the Agent):

```
{
  "parent": "projects/hr-oadbbl",
  "displayName": "HR",
  "defaultLanguageCode": "en",
  "timeZone": "Europe/Madrid",
  "enableLogging": true,
  "matchMode": "MATCH_MODE_HYBRID",
  "classificationThreshold": 0.3,
  "apiVersion": "API_VERSION_V2",
  "tier": "TIER_STANDARD"
}
```

However, when trying to use the `projects.agent.intents.list` method, directly in the browser, I'm being told "parent does not match pattern: /^projects/[^/]+/agent$/".
I've tried the following combinations: projects/hr-oadbbl, projects/hr-oadbbl/HR, hr-oadbbl/HR, projects/HR but can't seem to get this regex pattern right.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind - the answer was projects/hr-oadbbl/agent